# Proper Oracle ODBC Driver Installation on 32 bit Windows 7

Tags: oracle, excel, odbc, vba

I am using an Excel VBA application to connect to an Oracle 12c database.
Excel is 2010, 32 bit, in Windows 7.

Many have advised Oracle Instant Client, but this has not worked for me.  The installation requires a number of configuration steps that I cannot perform due to administrative restrictions on my workstation.

However, I have installed the ODAC 12.2c Release 1 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.2.0.1.0), available [HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html).  This package includes the Oracle ODBC driver which works for my application.  However, it contains several other components that I do not need, and throws some errors during installation that are disconcerting.

Can anyone tell me which of the following components I actually need to select in order to get the ODBC Driver?

[image: ODAC Options]

Since I cannot get InstantClient to work with my companies restrictions, I'm now aiming to use this package, but hopefully to slim it down to just the component I need.  I'm doing trial and error, but it's messy.  The installation takes a long time and there's no uninstaller, so I have to manually delete the files after installation.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Installing Oracle Instant client should solve your problem. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion akhil.  I have edited my question to reflect.

Comment: Why can you not install the Instant Client?  Their binaries are part of ANY Oracle installation.

Comment: Check the Oracle download page for ODBC Instant Client (or similar) Ensure to install the 32-bit version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest solution is to download the

**Instant Client Package - ODBC: Additional libraries for enabling ODBC applications** (instantclient-odbc-nt-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip)

from [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows 32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

You can also download the **ODAC with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio** from [ODAC Developer Downloads - Oracle Universal Installer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdev-4242174.html)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Domscheit.  I have been pulled off this assignment to fight a fire, but will attempt to implement your advice soon.  I will return with the results!

Answer (score 0):

Get the full **32-bit** Oracle client installer (not the ODAC) from here:

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle12c/122010/win32_12201_client.zip
```

Do an silent install using this reponse file (edit as needed and save as **client_install_32.rsp** in the same directory as setup.exe)

[Response file](https://pastebin.com/Vf8bsT9L)

```
setup.exe" ORACLE_HOME_NAME=OracleClient12201x32 -waitforcompletion -nowait -silent -responseFile client_install_32.rsp
```

The key config entry is this:

```
oracle.install.client.customComponents="oracle.rdbms.oci:12.2.0.1.0","oracle.network.client:12.2.0.1.0","oracle.odbc:12.2.0.1.0"
```

Comment: The 64-bit Client does not work with 32-bit Excel. Also there is no reason to download and install the full client.

Comment: Since the instant client is not an option, the only alternative is the full Oracle Client installer, associated with a response file to only install the required ODBC support + required dependencies... 
In addition, the other advantage of the full installer is that it takes care of all the configurations (no more manual registry and/or dll registrations)

Comment: Just a note, recently I installed Oracle 12.2 Client. Unlike earlier releases it did not register ODP.NET (`Oracle.DataAccess.dll` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`) into GAC anymore. I had to do it manually. Nevertheless, the ODBC driver was installed properly.

Comment: Another note, actually "Oracle Net" (`oracle.network.client`) would not be required. But due to a bug in Oracle 12 (12.1 and 12.2) you have to include it, see [Oracle Client 12.1.0.1.0 Custom Install Type Does Not Include ORACLSCE12.DLL (Doc ID 1589205.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1589205.1)

Comment: That's why I included it on my response file, because I already run into this issue...